# Legend doesn't float left on IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, legend

I am having trouble on IE7. I have following html format.

```
<fieldset class="wrapper">
    <legend class="ct">Legend </legend>
    <div class="ct">Div 1</div>
    <div class="ct">Div 2</div>
</fieldset>
```

And this is the css style

```
.wrapper .ct {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /*IE7*/
    float:left
}
```

when I test this on other browser it works fine but IE7 does not. Please see screenshot below. But if I use div instead legend then it works. Here is on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EZPY/2/)
[image]

Comment: Why would you use a `legend` element here? `legend` is used to provide the description of elements inside a `fieldset` and should (afaik) not be used outside `fieldset`s. I think a heading element (such as `h2`) is more appropriate here. `legend`s are really difficult to style as well, that's why I'm confused as to why you'd make it harder for yourself.

Comment: That's not valid HTML, the `legend` element is meant for `fieldset`s. [Contexts in which this element can be used: As the first child of a fieldset element.](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-legend-element)

Comment: I know what u mean. It is actually inside fieldset where divs are layering with legend. This is kind of format in CMS and I can't change.

Answer (score 1):

Andres almost had it. Add a "*float: none" after the "float: left" and you should be good.

```
.wrapper .ct {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    *display:inline;
    *float:none;
}​
```

[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2EZPY/11/)

Answer (score 0):

For IE7 only, try setting to display: inline (not inline-block).

Right, forgot how much a pain legend is.  You likely need to use absolute position to place it as such - with a left margin on the others or padding-left on the parent.  Depends on the design.

Answer (score 0):

IE does  not understand `display:inline-block`, you can use `display:inline` instead with a hack to target that browser alone, like so:

```
.wrapper .ct {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
    float:left
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. only works if I use div instead legend

Comment: @user1193749 Then use a `div`, or another suitable element. As @powerbuoy says in his comment, you shouldn't be using a `legend` tag.

Comment: well, this is system generated format so I can't change the markup.