# Floated divs dont sit side by side in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/arDtd/

Its find in every browser except for IE7 where the label doesnt sit side by side with the other content and instead sits above.

```
<div class="room_row">

    <div id="roomopts_2" class="jsHide"><fieldset class="form-wrapper" id="edit-room-options-2"><legend><span class="fieldset-legend">Room 2</span></legend><div class="fieldset-wrapper"><div class="hrCompact"><hr /></div><div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-adults-2">
  <label for="edit-adults-2">Adults </label>
 <select id="edit-adults-2" name="adults_2" class="form-select"><option value="1" selected="selected">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option></select>
</div>
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-children-2">
  <label for="edit-children-2">Children </label>
 <select id="edit-children-2" name="children_2" class="form-select"><option value="0" selected="selected">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
</div>
</div></fieldset>
</div>    </div>



div {
display: inline;
}    
.room_row {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}
.room_row fieldset.form-wrapper {
float: right;
width: 200px;
}
.form-wrapper {
display: block !important;
}
fieldset {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.room_row legend {
float: left;
clear: none;
}
.room_row .fieldset-wrapper {
float: left;
}
.fieldset-wrapper {
display: block;
}
hr {
display: none;
}
.room_row label {
display: none;
}

​
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [ie7 css hack](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/) (if you are alowed to) to fulfill your requirement

```
.fieldset-wrapper {
   display: block;
   *margin-left: 70px;
   *margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Here is the final [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arDtd/8/)

Hope this is usefull.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will use it if necessary but I was hoping to find out why this is happening so improve my understanding. Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, would a separate IE7 conditional stylesheet with the margin-left and margin-top be slightly more robust?

Comment: May [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020972/legend-doesnt-float-left-on-ie7) will help you to gain more clarity on this.